# Why are external NICs not working on my server (running on Debian 7)?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have a server running Debian 7. The eth0 interface is configured to use the on-board ethernet card. This is basically used to connect to the internet. As it happens, I had to connect this server to some PCs through a switch, obviously on a different series of IPs. for this, I installed an external NIC in the PCI slot but, strangely it didn't seen to work. The configurations were alright. I checked them more times than I can imagine. So, I disabled my eth0 interface and connected eth1 (external NIC) to the internet. If for the same settings, the on-board card worked, so should the external one. But, it didn't. When I tried to ping some servers like 8.8.8.8, it gives me Destination Host Unreachable and on termination shows, 0 packets "transmitted" and 0 packets received, which is baffling, to say the least. The PCI slot is working because I checked if the drivers were being recognised or not. The NIC itself is working (checked with another machine running Debian 6). Any help/sugesstions would be appreciated.

P.S The NIC in question is D-Link System DGE-530T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 11)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if the card is being listed in `lspci` or not. Second, is this a virtual machine?

I would also check to see if the BIOS is handling IRQ's in auto or are they specifically assigned.

Comment: Um, thanks but, I solved the problem a few weeks ago and forgot to update this post. My bad. The user who had been working previously on the same machine (server running Debian 7) had, for some reasons, installed Shorewall and set up rules for one-interface network. I didn't bother to check iptables because I didn't suspect that somebody had messed up with the firewall. Changing the iptable rules  did it for me.